# UITextView on cell clears when scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, cells

Hello fellow programmers,

I am really cracking my head trying to understand what the problem is, but I just can't seem to figure out the problem. I have done research on this but nothing works for me unfortunately. The problem is that I have multiple cells and each cell is given a specific UITextField which I draw on the cellForRowAtIndexPath programmatically. The issues is that when I enter some information on that any Text Field and I scroll down on the table view, the text on the text field disappears into thin air. I am trying to understand why the cell reuse (which I believe is causing the problem), is causing this.

Here is my code for the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }

    cellText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 10, 260, 20)];
    cellText.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0];
    cellText.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellText];

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        cellText.text = clientInfoArray[indexPath.row];

        if ([[clientInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Customer Name"])
        {
            nameTxtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 35, 300, 30)];
            nameTxtField.placeholder = @"full name";
            nameTxtField.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
            nameTxtField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
            [nameTxtField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
            [cell addSubview:nameTxtField];
        }
        if ([[clientInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Phone"])
        {
            phoneTxtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 35, 300, 30)];
            phoneTxtField.placeholder = @"xxx-xxx-xxx";
            phoneTxtField.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
            phoneTxtField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
            phoneTxtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypePhonePad;
            [phoneTxtField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
            [cell addSubview:phoneTxtField];
        }
        if ([[clientInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Date"])
        {
            dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 35, 300, 30)];
            dateLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:dateLabel];
            dateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        }
    }
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {

        cellText.text = vehicleInfoArray[indexPath.row];

        if ([[vehicleInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Make and Model"])
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            modelLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 35, 300, 30)];
            modelLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:modelLabel];
            modelLabel.text = makeAndModelData;

        }
        if ([[vehicleInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Color"])
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            colorLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 35, 300, 30)];
            colorLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:colorLabel];
            colorLabel.text = colorData;
        }
        if ([[vehicleInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Doors"])
        {
            doorsTxtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 35, 300, 30)];
            doorsTxtField.placeholder = @"#";
            doorsTxtField.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
            doorsTxtField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
            [doorsTxtField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
            doorsTxtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
            [cell addSubview:doorsTxtField];
        }
        if ([[vehicleInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Vehicle VIN"])
        {
            vinTxtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 35, 300, 30)];
            vinTxtField.placeholder = @"#";
            vinTxtField.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
            vinTxtField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
            [vinTxtField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
            vinTxtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
            [cell addSubview:vinTxtField];
        }
        if ([[vehicleInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Fuel"])
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            fuelLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 35, 300, 30)];
            fuelLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:fuelLabel];
            fuelLabel.text = fuelData;
        }
        if ([[vehicleInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Milage"])
        {
            milageLabel = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 35, 300, 30)];
            milageLabel.placeholder = @"ODO";
            milageLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
            milageLabel.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
            [milageLabel setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
            milageLabel.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
            [cell addSubview:milageLabel];
        }
        if ([[vehicleInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Other description"])
        {
            otherDTxtView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 35, 300, 125)];
            otherDTxtView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
            [cell addSubview:otherDTxtView];
        }
    }
    if (indexPath.section == 2) {

        cellText.text = InAndOutInfoArray[indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this problem? + Extra points for a helpful answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are using reuse cell techniques, the cell that is not visible will be deallocated to free some memory.

Since you are creating a textfield in the `cellForRow` method, it will also be deallocated when the cell is not visible and redrawn when it becomes visible.

You could save the textfield value in some array (using textfield's `didEndEditing` delegate) and use that array to populate the text during textfield creation process inside the `cellForRow` method.

Comment: You are indeed a genius. I saw what the problem is now and fixed the problem assigning the values and saving them. Thank you!